# Todo tasks from email

Tags: android, email

I am new to android programming and I am trying to make ToDo app with mail integration. Todo part is done, now I need to do "mail" part. I want app to take mail with proper title from mail client and parse message body to tasks (One row is one task). How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

That is up to the particular mail client that you want to integrate with.

I am not aware of any email apps that offer access to the user's mailbox, as that is typically considered private data that the user wouldn't want to openly share with other apps. If you know of one that offers this functionality, you should contact the developers of that app to find out how to integrate with it.

Some email providers such as Gmail provide APIs [such as this one](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android). This will require your users to sign in to your app with their Google account, and will not utilize the Gmail app at all, but will get you access to their email.